# Counting number of different characters in a word

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, counting

I am trying to think of a program to count the number of different characters in a word in Python.

For example:

- Given the input:

  ```
  ('Banana')
  ```
- Expected output:

  ```
  3
  ```

How can I use a `while` or `for` loop to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted anything yourself?

Comment: You don't need a loop for this. Look at `set`

Comment: Using a loop seems painful. You can always `len(set('banana'))`

Comment: imo you are better off figuring out how to do this entirely by yourself. Read about strings, and sets, and loops in python, and learn! If someone here tells you what to do, you will miss out on a valuable opportunity to challenge yourself. Unless of course there is an emergency :)

Comment: @Totem - Your suggestion of attempting this myself is valid, and honestly, I cracked my head trying to come up with the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** For future readers, this solution is only accepted because the OP was restricted to using loops. [@Andy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29756801/4669462) solution provides a much better alternative using Python's [`set()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#func-set) function.

Using a for loop:

```
word='Banana'

L=[]                           #create an empty list
for letter in word:
    if letter not in L:
        L.append(letter)       #append unique chars to list

print len(L)                   #count the chars in list
```

Comment: I think we should avoid this kind of fast and trivial answer just to take some rep (I did it in the past). If you remove it you'll do a good move: remove the noise and show the unique answer that have some valuable contents.

Comment: @Micheled'Amico Would it be okay if I just edit my post to point to the better answer? In my defense, this is what the OP wanted.

Comment: Yes point the right answer at the top of your is good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

A loop for this is not required. You can find the unique characters in a string using [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets)

```
len(set('Banana'))
```

This will output `3`. If you want to see what characters are unique, remove the `len` wrapper:

```
set('Banana')
```

Outputs:

```
set(['a', 'B', 'n'])
```

---

**Note:** `B` and `b` are unique. If you have a word like `Baby` you'll get this:

```
set(['a', 'y', 'B', 'b'])
```

To prevent this, convert your string to either all caps or all lower case:

```
set('Baby'.lower())
```

Outputs:

```
set(['a', 'y', 'b'])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> len(set('Banana'))
3
```

Comment: print len(set('Banana'))

Comment: @MostafaNorzade I'm not sure I understand.