# How can I count the amount of different characters in a string, i.e how many "t, r, u, e" characters are in the string str("true")

Tags: python, string, count, counter

Trying to count the amount of certain letters in the word true, what is a simpler way to do this?

I'm hoping for a simpler solution that will give me 4 as an answer!

Comment: `len(set('true')) # 4`.

Comment: How do you define "*certain letters*"? how does it generalize?

Comment: Also `collections.Counter(input_string)` may be of use, if you're interested in count of occurrences for every letter.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting number of different characters in a word](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29756708/counting-number-of-different-characters-in-a-word)

Answer (score 0):

You can use sets, but the exact approach depends on the exact expected logic.

```
target = {'t', 'r', 'u', 'e'}

### counting each unique letter that is also in target

word = 'true'

len(set(word) & target)
# 4

word = 'test'    # t and e are counted (once), not s

len(set(word) & target)
# 2


### counting all letters
# here t, e, t are counted, not s

sum(1 for c in word if c in target)
# 3
```